# PhpStorm 2019.3 read CakePhp translate as SQL command

Tags: cakephp, phpstorm, translation

As in title I have a frustrating problem when translating my application. When I try to write a translation similar to this:

```
    <?= __d('Plugin' , 'Delete functions from device') ?>
```

PhpStorm read this as Sql command and is looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB9cv.png) , but I need only text. I fix this by
using language injection:

```
/** @lang text */
```

but I have a question if it goes around this problem without using language injection?
Thank for any help.

Comment: That sentence is too "SQL-like" (`DELETE * FROM *`) and get matched as such by corresponding Language Injection rule. You've used the correct suppression for such case BTW. If you do not use such stuff and prefer plain text, just disable that particular rule in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections` -- look for SQL ones. You can also try and edit that bundled rule (or duplicate it first, disable bundled and edit your copy) to possibly skip such pattern, but then it will not match similar legit SQL in some another place.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for feedback. Disabling the option php:"SQL select/delete/inset/update/create" helped. Thanks a lot.